# Does threading in c# carry to other methods?

Tags: c#, multithreading

### Issue

---

I am streaming my camera out and want it to run on a separate thread as my UI is freezing. If I start a Thread on the first method call, does the methods inside that method go into the new thread or the old thread?

This is my setup at the moment.

### Code

---

**When the user clicks 'Start Stream':**

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartNewStream));
thread.Name = "streammm";
thread.Start();
```

**This calls 'StartNewStream' method which calls other methods:**

```
cam.OnSampleAvailable += (s, e) =>
{
    lock (BusyLock)
      rtspRecord.PushVideo(e.Sample);
};

win.OnSamplesAvailable += (s, e) =>
{
    lock (BusyLock)
       rtspRecord.PushAudio(e.Samples);
};
```

Do the methods PushVideo and PushAudio get called in the UI thread or the newly created thread?

If I go into the PushVideo method and put the code:

```
Thread TR = Thread.CurrentThread;
string _name = TR.name;
```

The name is now null?

Anyone help on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Im going to guess that if you set the onavailable's in your UI thread, its going to use the UI thread. whereas, if on creating the thread, you had set the onavailables in there, it would be the thread UI

Comment: The code within the event handler will execute on whatever thread dispatches the event. It doesn't matter which thread sets up the handlers.

Comment: You should examine not the name of the thread, as it can be null, but the [`ManagedThreadId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Whichever thread invokes the OnSampleAvailable event or delegate will also execute its handlers. It does not matter which thread assigns the handlers.

You must understand what your code actually does:

```
cam.OnSampleAvailable += (s, e) =>
{
    lock (BusyLock)
        rtspRecord.PushVideo(e.Sample);
};
```

This does not call anything at first. It only assigns an anonymous method `(s, e) => { ... }` as a handler to the event `cam.OnSampleAvailable`.

The handler is not called here. The assignment completes and as the end of your `StartNewStream` method is reached, **your new thread ends**. Then, much later, there may be samples available on your cam. Whichever thread is responsible (we do not know) will invoke the `cam.OnSampleAvailable` event, and the handler (the anonymous method `(s, e) => { ... }` you assigned earlier) will be executed **by that unknown thread**.

Comment: So at the moment Win and Cam are Global Variables inside the class? Would you create another class that handled all the streaming functions and set that as a separate thread?

Comment: @BenClarke The fact that they're global variables has *nothing* to do with this. Look at the *implementation* of the types. Whatever code is calling `OnSamplesAvailable.Invoke()` is what's important. However - you can dispatch a new thread inside the event handling code, which would then work on a separate thread.

Comment: The Single Responsibility Principle states that every class should have exactly one responsibility. So yes it might make sense to have a single class to handle your streaming. And it might make sense to have its code executed by a dedicated thread if it improves things, but that's up to you to decide.

Comment: @Rob `OnSamplesAvailable` is in the `StartNewStream` method that I created a new Thread for?

Comment: @BenClarke That's setting up listeners for the event. What matters is the code that dispatches an event.

Comment: The StartNewStream method **assigns** the handlers. This tells you nothing about which thread will eventually invoke the event/delegate and execute its handlers.

Comment: @Rob So how do dispatch PushVideo and PushAudio on the same thread as what StartNewStream is in?

Comment: We don't know. Because we don't know the implementation of those objects' types. We don't know which thread invokes the events.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation of `cam` and `win`. Likey either those two events are running on their own thread pool thread or they may run on the UI thread if they are written in a way that knows how to capture the `OperationContext`

Comment: Cam and Win are just Global variables in the class.

Comment: that does not matter, what matters is what is their type.